# nvcc on mac osx 10.9 unsupported option

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cuda, clang

When I try to compile any .cu file including a simple Hello World I get this error on the command line:

```
Agustin$ nvcc -o hello_world hello_world.cu
clang: error: unsupported option '-dumpspecs'
clang: error: no input files
```

I'm running OSX Mavericks 10.9

Here is the Cuda version:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_10_11:16:01_PDT_2013
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.5, V5.5.0
```

Also reading on the internet, if I excecuted the file like so:

```
nvcc -o hello_world hello_world.cu  -ccbin /usr/bin/clang
```

I get the following error

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/_*config(191):
>   error: identifier "*_char16_t" is undefined
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/_*config(192):
>   error: identifier "*_char32_t" is undefined
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config(303):
>   error: expected an identifier
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config(303):
>   error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config(304):
>   error: expected an expression
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config(305):
>   error: expected a ";"
>
> .............. *And many more lines of similar error printouts*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try updating to the new version of the cuda toolkit that was posted just recently for OSX 10.9 [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

Be sure to follow the [instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/index.html).

You may also be interested in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351219/cuda-clang-and-os-x-mavericks/19614009#19614009).

Answer (score 3):

The second problem probably comes from nvcc and libc++ not playing well together.
Try:

```
nvcc -o hello_world hello_world.cu -ccbin /usr/bin/clang -Xcompiler -stdlib=libstdc++
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar problem. As Robert mentions, this has to do with libstdc++ v.s. libc++ (the default for clang).

You can see this working CMake helloworld project here:
https://github.com/drtaglia/homebrew/tree/master/cuda_simple

In the main.cpp I also have manual compile instructions (you will have to tweak them slightly to match your paths)