# Mac OSx Maverick and CUDA 5.0: unsupported option '-dumpspecs'

Tags: c++, cuda, makefile

I am using CUDA 5.0 on maverick. I am trying to compile c/c++/cuda/fortran application. 
Before updating to maverick, my makefile (I am just using make, no cmake) worked ok. Now, whenever I try to compile using makefile, the c/c++ files compile fine but makefile stops executing while it encounters first .cu file.

I changed the makefile to:

```
NVCC := $(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/bin/nvcc 
CC   := /usr/bin/clang -lstdc++
CXX  := /usr/bin/llvm-g++
```

and

```
# NVCC flags
NVCCFLAGS := -ccbin=/usr/bin/clang -arch=sm_30
```

and I still get the error:

```
$ make
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/bin/nvcc  -ccbin=/usr/bin/clang -arch=sm_30  -DGLOBAL_DEF -DUNIX -O2 -m64  -I./INC -I/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/include  -o OBJ/spmv.o -c SRC/spmv.cu
clang: error: unsupported option '-dumpspecs'
clang: error: no input files
make: *** [OBJ/spmv.o] Error 1
```

Did anyone had/has similar problem or found solution?

Comment: note my answers on the linked question above and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649455/nvcc-on-mac-osx-10-9-unsupported-option)  A new cuda toolkit for 10.9 was just posted in the last couple days.